# Test database down with Spring

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-data

I need Spring tests for the app behavior during database(connection,down db..) error.
Is there a way to shutdown/kill or start the H2 in-memory db from the Spring unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

If testing DB connection, here is old, but still nice [blog on the topic](https://keyholesoftware.com/2016/10/03/automated-integration-tests-failure-scenarios/). You should be able to use TestContainers as well, for simpler DB creation.

If you need only test some failures on some exact actions (e.g. on repository save), you can simply mock the repository for the test run:

```
var mockedBean = Mockito.mock(MyRepository.class);
var originalBean = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(articleService, fieldName);
Mockito.when(mockedBean.save(Mockito.any(MyEntity.class))).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("My test exception"));
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myService, fieldName, mockedBean);
...
// test here
...
// set bean back for other test cases
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myService, fieldName, originalBean);
```

Answer (score 0):

When running Junit tests with a h2 test database, then the database instance will start when the test suite starts running and stop when tests are done (assuming you've configured your database using beans).

If you're using spring-boot, then you can configure your h2 test database like:

src/test/resources/application-test.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    username: sa
    password:
```

And configure your test like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
public class SignupControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private RealityKeeperRepository myrepo;
```

If you're using regular spring, then you can configure a DataSource bean with the `@Profile("test")` annotation:

```
@Bean
@Profile("test")
public DataSource devDataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .build();
}
```

And configure your tests like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    ...
```

Your AppConfig class should be annotated with @Configuration contain the devDataSource bean mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have H2 dependency and DO NOT have settings for it, then Spring boot will start embedded H2 DB for you.

This article should be useful: http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-h2-in-memory-database

Comment: Thanks, but in this article I did not found how to stop and start the db from running unit test.

Comment: Spring does it for you automatically

Comment: The OP is asking how to test database failures, not how to start a database.