# How to test Spring database down?

Tags: database, spring-boot, testing, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have this SpringBoot server app using PostgreSQL database if it's up and sending error response if it's down. So my app is running regardless the database connection.

I would very much like to test it (jUnit / mockmvc).

My question is very simple, yet I did not find the answer online: 
**how does one simulate a database connection loss in SpringBoot?**

If anyone wants, I can supply code (project is up at https://github.com/k-wasilewski/workshop/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test database down with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821999/test-database-down-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of Testcontainers? You can spin up your docker image through a Junit test and make your spring boot use that as your database.
Since you use junit, you can start/stop this container at will.
This will generate a test which creates the condition you are looking for and write code as to what to expect when the database is down.

Here are some links to get started,
Testcontainers and Junit4 with Testcontainers quickstart - https://www.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_4_quickstart/

Spring boot documentation - Use Testcontainers for integration testing
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-testcontainers

Testcontainer github link example for springboot app
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/tree/master/examples/spring-boot

Testcontainer - Generic container javadoc. You can find methods for start/stop
container here. call from your Junit.
https://javadoc.io/static/org.testcontainers/testcontainers/1.12.4/org/testcontainers/containers/GenericContainer.html

Comment: Already into it :) Right now I'm trying to figure out how to escape "Port 5432 already in use"

Comment: if port is set as property to your springboot app, you can let Testcontainers start at a random port , set up that port for the spring boot app to listen to and start it.

Comment: in case you need a sample, here is one. uses mongodb from springboot app. testcontainer sets up a mongo cluster, gets the ip/port etc, and starts the springboot app. will never get port conflict this way during test. https://gitlab.com/Oldtimes22/testcontainers/-/blob/master/mongodb/src/test/java/testcontainers/data/mongo/MongoApplicationTests.java

Comment: Thank a lot, but I get 'Connection to localhost:5432 refused' that I can't get rid of...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `Datasource` based on [`DelegatingDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DelegatingDataSource.html) and then let it throw exceptions instead of delegating when ever you want to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did set it up, but how does one make the test case use the DelegatedDataSource and not the original target one?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before by creating a Spring Boot test configuration class that created the DataSource and wrapped it in a Java proxy.  The proxy simply passed method calls down to the underlying DataSource, until a certain flag was set.  Once the flag was set, then any method called on the proxy would throw an exception without calling the underlying DataSource.  Essentially, this allowed me to "bring the database down" or "up" simply by flipping the flag.